# Android broadcast in service

Tags: android

I have a BroadcastReceiver class(Call Receiver), its waiting for incoming or outgoing call.
When my receiver is receive incoming/outgoing call i always save it to an SQLite database.

I have an AutoStarting class its work good, when i reboot my phone its always starting my Service.

So When my service is is created its always create a new Call Receiver, because we always waiting for an incoming/outgoing call.
Its a STICKY service.

When i test my program, its work good, but later... when someone calling me sometime its wrong. Broadcast receiver is cant receive valid data, or do not receive somethink.

Someone have idea, what i do wrong?
I hope someone can help me.
Im out of idea.

Thanks so much!

Service

public class MyService extends Service{

```
private MyReceiver rec;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
    filter.addAction("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL");

    rec = new MyReceiver();
    this.registerReceiver(rec, filter);
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

}

Receiver

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    Bundle bundle;
    String state;
String inCall, outCall;
public boolean wasRinging = false;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    MySingletonSQLite mySing = MySingletonSQLite.getInstance();


    switch (intent.getAction())
    {
        case "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE": 
        {
            if ((bundle = intent.getExtras()) != null) {
                state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                    inCall = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                    wasRinging = true;
                    // Ringing
                    mySing.add("incoming"+inCall);
                } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                    if (wasRinging == true) {
                        // Live
                        mySing.add("already live");
                    }
                } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                    wasRinging = false;
                    //Call ended
                    mySing.add("call ended");
                }
            }
            break;
        }

        case "android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL": 
        {

            if ((bundle = intent.getExtras()) != null) {
                outCall = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
                mySing.add("outgoing call"+outCall);
            }
            break;
        }

        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Can we see some code?  Stacktrace?  Description of what's not "working"?

Comment: Yes, i edited my post. Thanks